# How to get target of parent component in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to call parent component method on click of child component. After clicking the child component text in parent input field will change and save to reducer. But my parent method method is using target.value. I am not able to pass this target from child component.

I want to call the parent component's method on click of child component. After clicking child component text in parent input field will change and save to reducer. But my parent method method is using target.value.

I am not able to pass this target from child component.

Comment: Can you post your minimal code here. I think you should have a look on [this](https://dev.to/zeyadetman/how-to-pass-state-between-components-in-reactjs-2pg1)

Comment: actually i can not upload the code....but I can explain the requirement...I have a button and a text field in child component. I have passed the onchange function of parent component to child component's button. But now on click of that button I want to call onchange of input text box.

Comment: So basically you want to call 2 functions via `onChange()` function of a button right?

Comment: @shivangi You can share some code that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve. Please do so.

Comment: @swissArmyKnife7 yes....I want to onchange function of input text box on click of that button.

Comment: Be Descriptive in your questions as much as you can and avoid grammatical errors. Also I have posted and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood what you are telling is that a button in child component should should call 2 onchange() functions, One from the parent and another one of the input box.

**Parent Component**

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  // ....Parent Component OnChange Declared Here;

  render(){
    return(
      <ChildComponent OnChangeFromParent = {this.onChange()}/>
    )
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}

handleSubmit(event) {
  alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
  event.preventDefault();
}

render() {
// Calling two functions here on submit button click
  return (
    <form onSubmit="this.props.OnChangeFromParent(); this.handleChangeInputBox();">
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChangeInputBox} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
 }
}
```

Hope it clears some air.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass a callback function from the parent component down to the child

```js
const Parent = props => {

  const callback = ...args => {
    console.log('Ive been called with', args);
  }
  
  return (
    <Child callback={callback} />
  );
};


const Child = props => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.callback}>Im a button!</button>
  );
}
```